# Rewrite actionscript to javascript

Tags: javascript, actionscript

I´m trying to rewrite some actionscript code to javascript and I´m stucked at this function right now:

```
    function onRestart(){
     MovieClip(this.parent).thisVideo.ControlVideoAction("rewindall");
    }

    function onRew(e:MouseEvent):void{
     MovieClip(this.parent).thisVideo.ControlVideoAction("rewind");
    }
```

How do i rewrite the MovieClip sentence to javascript correctly?

Comment: its not that simple I'm afraid

Comment: take a look over haxe also...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By just converting the AS source code into valid JS the task is far from done. F.I. the class `MovieClip` does not exist in Javascript (Browsers) as well as the whole other Stuff you have in Action Script. There is no concept of a `Stage`, `Sprites` etc. The most promising solution for that might be the [Apache Flex](http://flex.apache.org/) project. That is the open source successor of Adobe Flash/Flex, which offers the so called [Falcon Compiler](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/FLEX/Falcon+Overview) which should offer a way to [compile for HTML and Javascript](https://www.itwriting.com/blog/5132-adobes-falcon-js-compile-flex-code-to-html-and-javascript.html). I have never tried it, but searched for AS to JS conversion, once I was asked for. So maybe that can do what you are after.